# Extra disablement property on many fields at once

Tags: c#, xaml, isenabled

I have a form containing many controls. In the list there's a **field that should disable all other controls** to prevent any further user action.

Would you know if there's a **simple way to do this?** Would like to not add the same disablement condition on all the fields one by one (on top of their own enablement logic)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a code example (never mind [a good, *minimal*, *complete* one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) it's not possible to provide specific advice. But you can enumerate all the controls in a form, and of course while doing so you can set the `Enabled` flag for each to `false`.

That might look something like this:

```
void SetEnabledForAllControls(ControlCollection controls, bool value)
{
    foreach (Control control in controls)
    {
        control.Enabled = value;
        SetEnabledForAllControls(control.Controls, value);
    }
}
```

You can call it by passing the `Form.Controls` value for your form as the `controls` parameter, and the new value (`true` or `false`) for the `Enabled` property of each control as the second parameter.

It's not clear from your question what the `field that should disable all other controls` is, but if that's a control itself in the same form, you'll want to remember to set its `Enabled` property back to `true` right after calling the above method, otherwise it'll wind up disabled as well.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I'm looking for. Will try to implement that